# How to embed one-to-one relation in Ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember 1.0-pre4.

I have two models in one-to-one relationship:

```
App.Lesson = DS.Model.extend                               
  timeslot: DS.belongsTo 'App.Timeslot'

App.Timeslot = DS.Model.extend
  lesson: DS.belongsTo 'App.Lesson'
```

I have an adapter configured to embed timeslot into lesson upon saving:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend()  

App.Adapter.map App.Lesson,    
  timeslot: { embedded: 'always' }             

App.Store = DS.Store.extend            
  revision: 11                                 
  adapter: App.Adapter.create()
```

Then I create a lesson and a time slot and try to save them:

```
lesson = App.Lesson.createRecord
  group: group
lesson.set('timeslot', App.Timeslot.createRecord())

lesson.store.commit()
```

But upon saving nothing is embedded and I see to POST requests, one for lesson and one for timeslot.

How do I tell Ember to always embed timeslot into lesson?

Comment: any fix for your issue ? Actually this works with the hasMany relationship only for one-to-one there is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug and you should report it. Sifting through the source code and doing some tests reveals that `createRecord` does not take into account the `embedded` configuration at all. This configuration is only used for the serialization and deserialization process.

When you make a call to createRecord, a record is added to a bucket, `created`,  and on `commit` `ember-data` simply fires an ajax post on every record in the bucket.

So to get back to your code, to `ember-data`, you created two records and on commits it will fire an ajax post call for the `Lesson` object with `Timeslot` `embedded` in it, AND will also, in a subsequent call, fires another ajax post for `Timeslot`, the last remaining record in the bucket.

```
lesson = QrTimetable.Lesson.createRecord
  group: group

lesson.set('timeslot', QrTimetable.Timeslot.createRecord())
lesson.store.commit()
```

Unless, someone with better understanding of the inners of ember-data contradicts my point, i tend to believe that, again, that this is a bug.

Here's the last code called when you commit the transaction.

```
  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var root = this.rootForType(type);

    var data = {};
    data[root] = this.serialize(record, { includeId: true });

    this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "POST", {
      data: data,
      context: this,
      success: function(json) {
        Ember.run(this, function(){
          this.didCreateRecord(store, type, record, json);
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr) {
        this.didError(store, type, record, xhr);
      }
    });
  },
```